# Cannot use initialization list on two overlapping structs

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, list-initialization

I want to use initialization list to initial the variable `p1` to simplify things for me. But it's not happening please help. Code is almost self explainatory.

```
struct word_t {
    int in;
    string word;
    int out;
    word_t(int i, string w, int o): in(i),word(w),out(o) {}
};


struct para_t {
    std::vector<word_t> words;
};

struct song_t { 
    std::vector<para_t> paras;
};    

int main()
{
    //SONG
    std::vector<song_t> song;

    para_t p1{ { 0, "We", 10 }, { 11, "are", 14 } , { 15, "the", 18 } 
    , { 19, "World", 22 } }; // CANNOT INITIALIZE LIKE SO 

    p1.words.push_back(word_t(0, "World", 10));   // THIS WORKS


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more `{}`, i.e.

```
para_t p1{ { { 0, "We", 10 }, { 11, "are", 14 } , { 15, "the", 18 } , { 19, "World", 22 } } };
//       ^                                                                                  ^ <- for para_t
//         ^                                                                              ^   <- for para_t::words
//           ^             ^                                                                  <- for elements (i.e. word_t) in vector
```

Comment: Works like charm ! +1 for quick response. But why extra braces?

Comment: @ark1974 because you want to call constructor of `para_t`.

Comment: @Afshin: Please elaborate.

Comment: @ark1974 Answer revised. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Yes. thanks again. Will check as answer in 5 min

Comment: @ark1974  You can create a member of `word_t` with something like this: `word_t w = { 0, "We", 10 };`. This calls a aggregate initialization that assigns each member. in `para_t` case, something similar happens. but this time member is vector. so you need 1 `{}` for calling initization, another `{}` for vector, and a list of `{}` for each `word_t`.

Answer (score 2):

If you initialize a vector of your `word_t`, it would be like this:

```
std::vector<word_t> song{ { 0, "We", 10 }, { 11, "are", 14 } , { 15, "the", 18 } 
, { 19, "World", 22 } };
```

But since your `std::vector<word_t> words;` is inside `struct para_t`, you have an extra level, so you should use an extra `{ }` around the initializer list.

Since it's the only member in the struct, consider to make it a typedef:

```
typedef std::vector<word_t> para_t;
para_t song{ { 0, "We", 10 }, { 11, "are", 14 } , { 15, "the", 18 } 
    , { 19, "World", 22 } };
```

So you won't need the extra brackets.

Comment: Cool technique using typedef +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add constructor for `para_t` that takes in `std::initializer_list<word_t>`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

struct word_t {
    int in;
    std::string word;
    int out;
    word_t(int i, std::string w, int o): in(i),word(w),out(o) {}
};


struct para_t {
    std::vector<word_t> words;
    para_t(std::initializer_list<word_t> v) : words{v} {}
};

struct song_t { 
    std::vector<para_t> paras;
};    

int main()
{
    para_t p1{ { 0, "We", 10 }, { 11, "are", 14 } , { 15, "the", 18 }, { 19, "World", 22 } };
}
```